# Problema com a montagem de consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho uma tabela de "disciplinas", uma tabela de "alunos" e uma tabela "alunosDisciplinas", onde esses alunos podem estar inscritos em uma ou mais disciplinas. Essas disciplinas são mostradas como checkboxes na tela de busca para servirem de filtro. Agora preciso listar todos os valores da tabela "alunos" de acordo com as disciplinas selecionadas, mas não estou conseguindo.

Essa é a Query que estou fazendo:

```
    public function buscaAvancada ($Busca, $Condicao)
    {
        $oConexao = new conexaoclass();
        $oConexao -> abrirConexao();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Alunos 
            INNER JOIN Disciplinas
            WHERE Alunos.Nome LIKE '%$Busca%'  
            AND Disciplinas.Nome = '$Condicao';";

        $this -> resultado = mysql_query($sql, $oConexao -> getConn());
    }
```

Na tela da busca estou fazendo o seguinte teste:

```
    if (empty($_POST['chkDisciplina'])) {
        $Busca = $_POST['txtbusca'];
        $_POST['chkDisciplina'] = '1';

        $oAluno = new alunosclass();
        $oAluno -> listar($Busca);
    }
    else{
        $Busca = $_POST['txtbusca'];
        $arrayFiltro = $_POST['chkDisciplina'];

        $separador = ' AND ';
        $Condicao = implode( $separador, $arrayFiltro );

        $oAluno = new alunosclass();
        $oAluno -> buscaAvancada($Busca, $Condicao);
    }
```

Aí agora o problema é na parte do filtro, pois se eu digitar apenas um txt na busca com todos os checkboxes desmarcados ele funciona perfeitamente.

Alguém teria alguma ideia?

Comment: A relação entre Alunos e Disciplinas é 1..N ?

Comment: Não, ela é de N...N em função dos alunos poderem ter quantas disciplinas quiser e vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu separador das condições não está separando corretamente a string passada via POST, o que resulta em uma query sem resultados.

Exemplo selecionando dois checkboxs (portugues e matematica) com o aluno 'juquinha'

```
SELECT * FROM Alunos 
INNER JOIN Disciplinas
WHERE Alunos.Nome LIKE '%juquinha%'  
AND Disciplinas.Nome = 'portugues AND matematica';
```

Altere seu separador para `$separador = "' AND '";` e você terá o seguinte resultado:

```
SELECT * FROM Alunos 
INNER JOIN Disciplinas
WHERE Alunos.Nome LIKE '%juquinha%'  
AND Disciplinas.Nome = 'portugues' AND 'matematica';
```

**OBS**: Após um teste rápido, acredito que seja preciso também repetir o `Disciplinas.Nome` em cada condição:

`$separador = "' AND Disciplinas.Nome = '";`

Resultando na query:

```
SELECT * FROM Alunos 
INNER JOIN Disciplinas
WHERE Alunos.Nome LIKE '%juquinha%'  
AND Disciplinas.Nome = 'portugues' AND Disciplinas.Nome = 'matematica';
```

Uma boa maneira de debugar suas querys é fazendo um `echo` da variável com a query gerada e copiando esse código no programa que você usa para gerenciar seu banco ([phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) ou [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) por exemplo)